# How do I use link in google maps

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently trying to add link_to to the prices on my map. 
The problem that I'm facing is that by clicking the price, it doesn't redirect the user to the specific show page.
When I look at the url it doesn't change from /search to -> wines/1 for example.

This is the code I'm trying with:

```
wines.forEach(function(wine) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: {lat: wine.latitude, lng: wine.longitude},
        map: map
    });
    windowContent = "<div class='map_price'>Ab " + wine.price + "€</div>";
    windowContent += "<div><%= escape_javascript link_to(@wine) %></div>";

    inforwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
        content: windowContent
    });

    inforwindow.open(map, marker);
});
}
```

Comment: Where the variable `@wine` is defined?? Could you share the code of your controller and view??

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to render links in Rails and because you are usering javascript to render all wines on Map(I hope each `wine` contains `id` with other details), I would suggest to use `anchor` tag instead of Rails `link_to` method as follow...

```
wines.forEach(function(wine) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: {lat: wine.latitude, lng: wine.longitude},
        map: map
    });
    windowContent = "<div class='map_price'>Ab " + wine.price + "€</div>";
    windowContent += "<div><a href='http://yourdomain.com/wines/'+wine.id target='_blank'>View</a></div>";

    inforwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
        content: windowContent
    });

    inforwindow.open(map, marker);
});
```